# Mini PC JK01: how to install a 2.5" inch HDD (disk)?

Tags: hard-drive, sata, intel-nuc

I got a "Mini PC" model: JK01.
All literature (over the network) claims that it has a "2.5" inch SATA HDD bay".

(For example: [mini PC review](https://www.notebookcheck.net/JK01-Budget-mini-PC-launches-with-an-Intel-Jasper-Lake-processor-for-US-140.584094.0.html))

But when I open the "mini PC", I can't find any "HDD SATA bay"! (I do see the memory and SSD cards).

Comment: If you open it up, there might be space for an M.2 SSD *on the inner side of the lid*.

Comment: Do you see screw holes in the bottom lid? If so that is your 2.5" SATA "bay". Typically you'll find a non-standard cable connection in the board (different brand but it can be the same): https://support.hystou.com/how-to-add-sata-ssd-hdd-to-h5-mini-pc/

Comment: @harrymc: as I mentioned in the OP, I already have an SSD card installed. I specifically meant a 2.5" inch SATA HDD (which is mentioned and promised), but I don't see power and data ports for it.

Comment: @ChanganAuto: I have a "JK01" model "mini PC" (it also says: "FICEP" on the top lid). I don't see a SATA (data) connection on the board.

Comment: If so you should contact who sold it as ask.

Comment: Other vendors I saw for the JK01 only mentioned the M.2 SSD, not a 2.5" inch SATA HDD. The information you got was either erroneous or related to a different model.

Comment: It uses a M.2 ssd, more like a card slot

Comment: The 2.5" SSD is using the 2.5" slot. SATA is the connector interface, not so much the drive type. The SSD, if it is a 2.5 drive, is using the power and data cables that you're looking for. So far, based on what you've told us, this system has what you are looking for, but you're not recognizing it.